# How can I help TextMate recognize which bundle to load?

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

I have a problem with four bundles I'm using, specifically Ruby, Ruby on Rails, RSpec and Sinatra.

Most of the time TextMate manages to get the bundle type right, but for these, I find myself constantly switching form Sinatra to Ruby on Rails, as some model files get recognized as Sinatra.

It also happens a lot with RSpec, where the Sinatra bundle sometimes takes precedence.

**Is there any way to manage the way in which bundles are recognized?** It would be great if I could somehow hint TextMate what bundles to completely ignore in a specific project, or based on a directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can modify your Sinatra bundle to trigger as soon as it detects `require 'sinatra'`